# How to create Kendo filter for Date-picker?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have below config where i am loading the data in the grid so here i have added date-picker in the filter but once user select the value from date-picker its not being filter.Any help will be appreciated i am not sure where i am implementing wrong.

So far tried code..

config.js

```
     getall: {
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        editable: false,
        filterable:{
          extra: false,
          operators: {
              string: {
                  startswith: 'Starts with',
                  eq: 'Is equal to',
                  contains: 'Contains'
              }
          }
      },
        pageable: {
          pageSizes: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
      },
        columns: [
    {
                field: 'cycStartDate',
                title: 'Cycle Start',
                width: '300px',
                filterable: {
                  ui: function (element) {
                      'use strict';
                      element.kendoDatePicker({
                          format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                      });
                  },
                  operators: {
                      string: {
                          eq: 'Is equal to'
                      }
                  }
              }
              }
]
```

Comment: What does 'use strict'; do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can help.

```
{
    field: 'cycStartDate',
    title: 'Cycle Start',
    width: '300px',
    filterable: {
        extra: false,
        operators: {
          string: {
              eq: 'Is equal to'
          }
        },
        ui: function (element) {
          element.kendoDatePicker({
              format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
          });
        }
    }
}
```